# SQL Server 'Connect to server' SQL service was not found under services.msc

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So today I downloaded the latest version of SQL Server from this [official website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). I downloaded both setup the installer and the upgrade package. 
I ran them both 'as administrator' on my machine. And the installation went successfully.

But after that when I run the SQL Server Management Studio for a very first time. It promotes me to connect to the server as expected.

But when I hit connect am getting following error message.

[image: SQL server error]

So I searched the internet for the same issue. From one of the question, I got the hint that to start SQL server service manually by going to `services.msc` app.

But there wasn't any service related to SQL Server. Weird.

So what I am supposed to do now?

Comment: Did you even download and install the server? Or only SSMS? Or do you already have one running somewhere? It's a little odd that you say "I downloaded the latest version of SQL server from this official website" yet the link points to a page titled "Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)" (and is indeed for downloading SSMS).

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed SQL Server; just SSMS. You need to download and install SQL Server as well. It seems you are very new to SQL Server though, so I suggest learning about it before you install it. Maybe Google a tutorial or, even better, read the documentation. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: yeah actually am very new to SQL server. Am a C# developer. And want to use SQL server as my backend database. That's why I downloaded SSMS.

Comment: which edition of sql server should i donwload? Any suggestion on it! Am a CS student.

Comment: Both  SQL Server Express Edition and SQL Server Developer Edition will be appropriate for development purposes. Once you create a "production" system, you'll need to either pay for a license for the appropriate edition, or continue using Express Edition if it can handle the workload.